# Blazor page results show different with and without NavMenu

Tags: blazor

I am self study blazor from Microsoft Learning.
But I do not know why I follow original tutorual and keep using NavMenu.
And the result is quite different with what show in tutorual.

Can anyone help to answer?
Here is the Url what I learn from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/interact-with-data-blazor-web-apps/3-exercise-create-user-interfaces-with-blazor-components
[image: This is the page show up in tutorual]

[image: This is the page show up with NavMenu]

Comment: Hmm, it may relate to css, Can you put the `pizza` page code here?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/

Comment: I am wondering blazor component should be able to put into any razor page.  But looks like there is some constrain in blazor component.